# ruby function with loop return the wrong value

Tags: ruby

I have a problem about the code

```
@nums = [3, 2, 4]
@target = 6

def two_sum(nums, target)
  random1 = nums.sample
  random2 = nums.sample
  ary1 = [nums.index(random1), nums.index(random2)].sort
  if random1 + random2 == target
   return ary1
  else
    return 1
  end
end

loop do
  if two_sum(@nums, @target) != 1
    print two_sum(@nums, @target)
    break
  end
  puts 2
end
```

This code should return the indices of two elements in `[3, 2, 4]` whose sum is `6`, i.e. either `[1, 2]` or `[0, 0]`. But occasionally `1` appears, although it shouldn't.

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this part of the code:

```
if two_sum(@nums, @target) != 1
  print two_sum(@nums, @target)
```

you are making two **separate** calls to the `two_sum` function, once in the `if` and then a second time in the `print`. So if the first result isn't equal to 1 you'll make a second call (which could return 1) and print the result from that second call.

Instead, you could capture the result of a single call to `two_sum` and print that e.g.

```
loop do
  result = two_sum(@nums, @target)
  if result != 1
    print result
  ...
```

or combining the assignment and comparison if you prefer:

```
if (result = two_sum(@nums, @target)) != 1
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method's return value depends on a call to `sample`, i.e. it returns a random – and therefore potentially different – element each time. The method name `two_sum` however does not indicate its impure nature. If the method was called `random_two_sum`, the bug would have been a lot more obvious:

```
if random_two_sum(@nums, @target) != 1
  print random_two_sum(@nums, @target)
  break
end
```

So unless you want that randomness, a better approach is to yield the values one after another using an [`Enumerator`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerator.html):

```
def each_two_sum_index(nums, target)
  return enum_for(__method__, nums, target) unless block_given?
  nums.each_index.to_a.repeated_combination(2) do |i, j|
    yield i, j if nums[i] + nums[j] == target
  end
end
```

You can then invoke the method with a block instead of using an explicit `loop`:

```
each_two_sum_index([3, 2, 4], 6) do |i, j|
  p i: i, j: j
end
```

Output:

```
{:i=>0, :j=>0}
{:i=>1, :j=>2}
```